# weak property for delegate cannot be formed

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting

I have a property that looks like this:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<NavigationControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

But when I run my app I get the following error:

```
objc[4251]: cannot form weak reference to instance (0x101e0d4b0) of class TabBarController
```

The only reason I can get from google for this error is that you get it when you try to form a weak reference to an object that overrides retain/release/dealloc, which I am not. My TabBarController is inheriting from NSViewController.

Anyone knows what might cause this? It works if I use "assign", but obviously I'd prefer to use "weak".

Comment: CocoaFu, "cannot form weak reference to instance ..." is always a runtime error.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

According to Apple's [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW17),

> You cannot currently create weak references to instances of the following classes:
>
> `NSATSTypesetter`, `NSColorSpace`, `NSFont`, `NSMenuView`, `NSParagraphStyle`, `NSSimpleHorizontalTypesetter`, and `NSTextView`.
>
> Note: In addition, in OS X v10.7, you cannot create weak references to instances of `NSFontManager`, `NSFontPanel`, `NSImage`, `NSTableCellView`, **`NSViewController`**, `NSWindow`, and `NSWindowController`. In addition, in OS X v10.7 no classes in the AV Foundation framework support weak references.

(Note: one needs to be very careful with nonzeroing weak references...)

Comment: Great stuff! I suspected there was something different with the NSViewController based on my findings before. I hadn't seen what you just pasted though. Thanks, that definitely clarifies the whole thing!