# unsafe_unretained vs weak : crash during setDelegate

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have some doubts about **unsafe_unretained** and **weak** keywords: as a read they are quite the same and the only difference is that the **weak** one is set to null if the pointed object is released.

Now I the code below and it crash at point [#2] during the *[instanceOfTheView setDelegate:self]*

but if in I4vMainView declaration [#1] I substitute

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <I4vDraggingFileProt> delegate;
```

with

```
@property (nonatomic, unsafe_unretained) id <I4vDraggingFileProt> delegate;
```

it works perfectly. What is the reason for this behavior? Thanks

Details: Target 10.7 compiling with ARC. Xcode 4.5.2 . Apple LLVM 4.1

In the class I4vMainView I have:

```
//----------- I4vMainView.h --------
@protocol I4vDraggingFileProt <NSObject>
   -(void) anURLWasDeopped: (NSURL *) droppedUrl;
@end    

@interface I4vMainView : NSView <NSDraggingDestination>{
    NSImageCell *imageCell;
    NSImage * image;
}

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <I4vDraggingFileProt> delegate;  // [#1]
```

While in the caller

```
//----------- I4vViewController.h --------
@class I4vMainView;

@protocol I4vDraggingFileProt <NSObject>
    -(void) anURLWasDeopped: (NSURL *) droppedUrl;
@end

@interface I4vViewController : NSViewController <I4vDraggingFileProt>{
    I4vMainView * mv;
}

-(void) anURLWasDeopped: (NSURL *) droppedUrl;

@end


//----------- I4vViewController.m --------
@implementation I4vViewController
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)loadView{
    mv = [[I4vMainView alloc] init];
    [mv setDelegate:self];    // <-- [#2]
    [self setView:mv];       
}

-(void) anURLWasDeopped: (NSURL *) droppedUrl{
    // ...
}

@end
```

**Add:**

With delegate declared as

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <I4vDraggingFileProt> delegate;
```

i have this Error

```
<I4vMainView: 0x10060bf40> objc[4773]: cannot form weak reference to instance (0x10061bf10) of class I4vViewController
```

and back-trace goes thoroughly _objc_trap <- objc_stroreWeak <- -[I4vMainView setDelegate:] <- [I4vViewController view]

[image]

Comment: The difference between `unsafe_unretained` and `weak` is that `weak` references are set to `nil` when the referenced object is deallocated, not when the referenced object is released. Big difference. Also, `weak` requires iOS 5.0 or later. `unsafe_unretained` works in iOS 4.3. I'm not sure what versions of OS X supports `weak`.

Comment: Can't you just print the value of mv inside loadView?

Comment: by term "released" i was meaning deallocated, terms error. I'm coding in Cocoa, the weak keyword work perfectly for all my IBoutlets

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri  what do you mean by "just print the value" ? the pointer is not null and alloc and int are successful

Comment: Do you get anything printed out to the debug log upon the crash? Usually there's some decently helpful information in the log.

Comment: @rmaddy Weak supports iOS >= 5.0

Comment: @Sabby Please read my comment again. I stated that iOS supports weak in iOS 5.0 and later. I stated I don't know what version of OS X supports weak.

Comment: @maddy alright,  I got that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer: as said in [weak property for delegate cannot be formed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193445/weak-property-for-delegate-cannot-be-formed)

> You cannot currently create zeroing-weak references to instances of the following classes (emphasis mine):
>
> NSATSTypesetter, NSColorSpace, NSFont, NSFontManager, NSFontPanel, NSImage, NSMenuView, NSParagraphStyle, NSSimpleHorizontalTypesetter, NSTableCellView, NSTextView, NSViewController, NSWindow, and NSWindowController. In addition, in OS X no classes in the AV Foundation framework support weak references.
>
> For declared properties, you should use assign instead of weak; for variables you should use __unsafe_unretained instead of __weak.
>
> In addition, you cannot create weak references from instances of NSHashTable, NSMapTable, or NSPointerArray under ARC.